# How to show three tables data using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to show data from three tables using Entity Framework.

I have these three tables:

1. roles
2. groups
3. group_roles

The first table `roles` has two columns `roles_id int` primary key and 
`role_name`

The second table `groups` also has two columns `group_id` primary key and `group_name`.

And the third table `group_roles` has three columns:

```
group_roles_id primary key,
group_id foreign key groups (groups_id)
role_id foreign key roles (roles_id)
```

I have created a custom class `new_group_roles` with the following properties:

```
public class NewGroupRoles
{
    public group_roles group_roles { get; set; }
    public int[] selectedroles { get; set; }      
    public IEnumerable<group> groups { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<role> roles { get; set; }
}
```

I am successful at inserting data, but I want to show the data in the following manner

```
group_roles_id -- Group Name --- roles
```

I have written a function in the model which I am calling in the controller from this function all the data will come

Here is the code

```
public group_roles GetAllGroups()
{
    try
    {
        using(var p = new VMSDBContext())
        {
            var group = (from group_role in p.group_roles
                         join grups in p.groups on group_role.group_id equals grups.group_id
                         join roles in p.roles on group_role.roles_id equals roles.role_id
                         select new NewGroupRoles()
                             {
                                group_roles =group_role.group_id

                             }).ToList();

            return p.group_roles.Include("group").Include("role").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return new group_roles();
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't assign properties of the `new_group_roles` class.

Can anybody help me how to do this? Or is there any better approach? Keep in mind I want to return data from model folder to controller not directly from controller

Thanks

Comment: Your `var group = ...` code does nothing because you are not using it anywhere else in your example and you are returning the first row form table group_roles. Also your new class is therefore "useless", you should at least rewrite the method to `public NewGroupRoles GetAllGroups()` and see where you get from there